# Android foreground service vibration when updating notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, foreground-service

I have a foreground service which is used to upload file and show the progress of it via notification.

The code below I'm posting works pretty good, except that on every update event, it vibrates.

My code to start a foreground service and init the notification is as below.

```
//this method is called on onStartService().
void startForegroundService() {

        mCompatBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.img_checkbox);
        mCompatBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        mCompatBuilder.setTicker("Ticker");
        mCompatBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        mCompatBuilder.setContentTitle("Uploading");
        mCompatBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);
         mCompatBuilder.setContentText("0%");
        mCompatBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mCompatBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        mCompatBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);
        mCompatBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        mCompatBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
        mCompatBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0L});

        startForeground(1, mCompatBuilder.build());
}
```

The progress update part is as below.

```
public void updateProgress(int progress, String contentText) {


        mCompatBuilder.setContentText(contentText);
        mCompatBuilder.setProgress(100, progress, false);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mCompatBuilder.build());
}
```

I've tried to lower the priority of the notification, and also tried to set the setVibration to new long{0L}. But neither of it seems to be working.

What else can I try? Please help!

Comment: Did you try setting the notification warning to the lowest?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NotificationChannels/issues/18

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing this line? `mCompatBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0L});`